# Библиотека для воспроизведения на Android своих .sf2 файлов

Tags: android

Необходимо при проигрывании *midi* брать звуки из своих банков звуков. 
Когда не было необходимости использовать свой банк звуков использовалась библиотека «https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver», но заставить её работать с не её банками не удалось.

Есть ли библиотеки с такой возможность? Какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: "нее банками" - уточните, что вы имели в виду.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел плеер с нужным функционалом "https://github.com/agangzz/SherlockMidi". Но присутствует минус, есть ощущаемое запаздывание между нажатием на кнопку и издаваемым звуком, видимо так как написан на java